# Ubuntu 19.04 Black Artifacts around X (Close button) when using shell theme

Tags: unity, gnome, themes

I am currently using the Arc Application and Shell theme. These artifacts have appeared [X button overlap with artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4negC.png)

This occurs on any shell theme other than default and it seems that the themes are over lapping each other.

I remember seeing a similar post in the past but I can't find it anymore.

How do I get rid of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the theme doesn't support this version of GTK. A Solution would be to override the window close CSS for your theme. Navigate to your theme folder and change .window-close to the following.

Folder Location:

/usr/share/themes/**YOUR THEME NAME**/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css

Replace with this:

```
.window-close {
height: 32px; width: 32px;
background-color: transparent;
border-radius: 0;
border: none;
box-shadow: none;
color: transparent;
-shell-close-overlap: 16px;
-st-background-image-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
background-image: url("assets/window-close.svg");
background-size: 32px;
}
```

Source:
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-glitch-on-gnome-activities-overview/85485